# select divs and put into collection using htmlagilitypack not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

Why does this not work? I get a null reference exception error on the foreach loop as it starts

I'm trying to get all the divs text on a page and put each one into my own collection

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Xml

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim webGet As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("http://www.mysite.com")

        Dim ids As New List(Of String)()

        For Each div As Object In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")

            ids.Add(div.InnerText)

        Next



    End Sub
End Class
```

***exception***

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:         Dim ids As New List(Of String)() 
>   Line 13:
>   Line 14:         For Each div As Object In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")
>   Line 15:
>   Line 16:             ids.Add(div.InnerText)

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Is `htmlDoc` null?  Is `htmlDoc.DocumentNode` null?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Perhaps the URL "http://www.mysite.com" is not returning a valid HTML.

The code below works:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim webGet As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/q/11528387/1350308")

        Dim ids As New List(Of String)()
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        For Each div As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")
            TextBox1.Text += div.Id + Environment.NewLine
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

The result in TextBox1 is:

```
noscript-padding
notify-container
overlay-header
custom-header

header
portalLink
topbar
hlinks
hsearch

hlogo
hmenus


content

question-header
mainbar
question
adzerk1

















comments-11528387


answers
answers-header

tabs
answer-11528559








comments-11528559

post-editor

wmd-button-bar

draft-saved
draft-discarded
wmd-preview









sidebar
newuser-box



adzerk2
hireme



























feed-link
feed-link-text

prettify-lang
footer

footer-menu
footer-sites
footer-flair
svnrev
copyright
noscript-warning
```

Complete source: [Q11528387WebApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11528387WebApp.7z)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the version of "HtmlAgilityPack.dll." I am using the version "1.4.0.0". I put the "complete source" in the answer above.

Comment: Do you know where I can download it again from do you have a direct link to 1.4.0.0 or 1.4.2.0 - do you have a direct link to the dll

Comment: You can see the list with all versions here: http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I know about that but it dosnt work properly - To install HtmlAgilityPack, run the following command in the Package Manager Console but it installs 1.4.5.0

Comment: Use "Nuget package Explorer" to get the dll (http://npe.codeplex.com). With it you can choose the version you want to download more easily. Click "Open a package from online feed" -> fill text box with "HtmlAgilityPack" -> Uncheck "Only show latest version..." -> click "search" -> Double-click on the version of your choice -> "File" -> "Export".