# html agility pack wont return any ids even though the page has ids?

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack, vb.net-2010

Why wont this code return any ids in the generic list. The web page definitely has ids in the div elements.  If I break point it, there are no ids in the property `Id` in `DocumentNode.SelectNodes` and `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id]")` does not work.  I am using .NET 2.0 and HtmlAgilityPack.dll 1.4.0.0.

```vb
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim listHtmlFound As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim webGet As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/q/11528387/1350308")
        htmlDoc.OptionUseIdAttribute = True
        'Dim s As Object = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id").Count
        For Each div As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")
            listHtmlFound.Add(div.Id)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Is the problem that `div.Id` returns null inside the loop?  Or is the problem that `SelectNodes` returns an empty list so it never enters the loop?

Comment: sorry about that - SelectNodes does not have any id values

Comment: So, `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id").Count` is zero?

Comment: I get a nulreferenceexeption error - any ideas -- thanks

Comment: What's null?  Is `htmlDoc` null?  Is `htmlDoc.DocumentNode` null?  Or does `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id")` return null?

Comment: hi - htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id") returns null, and htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div") returns lots of divs but the id property for all of them is empty

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need this:

```
 htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id]")
```

to select all `<div>` nodes having an `id` attribute, instead of all `id` attributes themselves?

**EDIT**
If the `Id` property of `HtmlNode` doesn't work, you could always use the `Attributes` property: loop through that to find one with `Name = "id"` and use it's `Value`.

Comment: Nope it does not work - even if I break point and stop and inspect htmlDoc.DocumentNode, there is no value at the id property

Comment: The documentation notes: "The document must have been parsed using the OptionUseIdAttribute set to true. " for that Id property to be filled.

Comment: @Hello-World - maybe you should now update the code in your question.